# What is the difference between returning void and ResponseEntity<Void> in Spring Boot RestController?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, http-status-code-204, response-entity

I wonder what the difference is between the return value of a Spring Boot RestController if void shall be returned?

I can see do difference in a test in either way. It seems that even if I return void the `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` (204) is returned to the requester as well as if I use `ResponseEntity<Void>`.

So, when I return `void` from an endpoint the HttpStatus is returned anyway and it doesn't matter if I choose `void` or `ResponseEntity<Void>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly. You would need the `ResponseEntity<Void>` if you want to add some headers.

Comment: In my test I do mockMvc... .andExpect(status().isNoContent()); 
and it is successful in either way. So, when the return type is primitive void the HttpStatus seems to be send to the requestor as well. so why should I use ResponseEntity<Void>? what is the benefit? So, if I don't want to add any other header it doesn't matter which return type to use? The HttpStatus will be returned alway?

Comment: That's what I wrote in my answer: "You would need the ResponseEntity<Void> if you want to add some headers."

Comment: @du-it in your case you can safely return void from controller's method